# Android: Using retrofit although my code always returns false

Tags: android, if-statement, return, boolean, retrofit

This code always returns false:
http://pastebin.com/pxz4DUEm

Even though it logs success etc... It seems as though the bottom return statement is triggering before my "IF" statement has finished. I cannot delay the return statement as the user may have very slow internet.

Comment: As a bonus, I CANNOT return inside the Retrofit statement...

Comment: Please edit your post to provide additional content instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside your `Callback` is executed asyncronously.

With API.getMembership you only *register* a `Callback`, it is not *executed* right away. Instead your code continues with the statements below.

You should learn about anonymous inner classes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html